# How can I make my ajax send a query to my php page from a modal

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, modal-dialog

I'm trying to change a query in my database for if a specific button is clicked and they confirm they want to complete command. I have a button that I want to make reset all the stats in my database. For example, the site name, site motto, I want them all reset to the default values I have in my php file. When I click the button, I want to make it so a confirm dialog pops up (working now). I want to make it so when i click confirm reset on the modal, it executes my ajax command. How would I go about making my ajax send to my php in a modal ? My modal is working, just not the ajax.

**My code :**

***HTML BUTTON***

```
<button type="submit" id="button2" name="button2" class="btn btn-inverse" onclick="checkConfirm();">
     <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
</button>
```

***JavaScript / AJAX***

```
<script>
function checkConfirm() {
    swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "By pressing Yes, you will reset all current database statistics such as money made, purchases made and so on. You will not be able to recover any of the current statistics you have now!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, reset stats!',
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        },
        function(isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                swal("Reset!", "Your current statistics have been completely reset! Any statistics you had before, have now been reset to default values.", "success");
                var postResetSend = 1;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "includes/reset_statistics.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { postReset: postResetSend },
                    success: function(data) {
                        window.location.replace("admin_site.php");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                swal("Cancelled", "Your current statistics are safe and have remained the same. Nothing in the database has been altered.", "error");
            }
        });
};
</script>
```

***MY PHP FILE***

```
if(!isset($_POST['postReset'])) {
    header('Location: error-pages/index.php');
} else if(isset($_POST['postReset'])) {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE sitesettings set site_name='TeamXerone', team_motto='The Art of Modding', dash_version='17511', site_owner='Ben', user_session_timeout='600', default_user_insert_password='$2y$10$iYg9mVJAUeUMdTyVzYCZuO4QipCg/nnp70VVilBvxKDvr1yyCE9S.', site_url='http://localhost/zackend', paypal_email='admin@hotmail.com', WHERE id='1'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out my code was correct. My problem was that I wasn't letting my file be accessed in my .htaccess.

I fixed by defining my file name.
For example (my .htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(reset_statistics)\.php
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```